# Slow Connection Pool in Weblogic 10 and Oracle 10

Tags: sql, oracle, weblogic, connection-pooling

We are currently moving from Weblogic 8 and Oracle 8 to Weblogic 10 and Oracle 10 as a big upgrade project.

It appears that for most applications, they are running faster, better and staple. However, for some particular application, which heavily uses connection pools, such as open/close multiple connections at the same time, uses multiple connection pools in the same application, it is much SLOWER, which really confused me.

The connection pools in the new servers are exactly same settings as on the old ones. There is NO connection leaks in the application.

Any suggestion will be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Look into [JDBCConnectionPoolParamsBean](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E12840_01/wls/docs103/wlsmbeanref/core/index.html). We faced similar problem. The setting that helped us was setting Remove Infected Connections Enabled - false

Answer (score 0):

Did you make sure the statement cache is defined to be the same size in WebLogic 10 as well? Also, since WebLogic 10 uses Java 5 (or 6 if you're using the latest releases), the optimal JDBC driver to use would be ojdbc5.jar instead of ojdbc14.jar (provided that you're using an Oracle database).

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

We found the problem, and it was due to a concatenation operation || in the SQL statements. The weird thing is this this SQL runs fast in oracle 8 but slow in 11...Probably a bug.